# Azure Data Factory Truncate prescript taking too long as data size increases

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to load data from the Azure SQL server into a snowflake data warehouse. I am using the truncate table script in the pre-script section of sink data to completely remove the data from the destination and insert all of the data that's in the source table. It's fast when the data size is small but once the data size gets really big the entire copy activity takes hours to complete the sync. What other alternatives can I use to copy data from my source to the destination?

I thought about using Upsert instead of truncating and inserting but since it's going to check each record I assumed that it will be slower.

Comment: follow this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance) to improve the performance of copy activity.

Comment: Did you try Truncate table script in snowflake DWH for large data? Is it taking longer time than for small data?

Comment: I am truncating the table in the pre-script section of ADF sink. It doesn't take much when copying small data but takes almost an hour to copy large datasets. I was looking into ways of optimization of my current apporach.

Comment: @Adx As per  [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#staged-copy)
You can try staged copy using Snowflake connector. This copies data from source to staging storage first and then staging to Sink. This feature gives flexibility to store data in compressed format at staging and then decompress and store it on Sink.

Comment: Yes, I have used the snowflake connector using blob as a staging area partitioning the source data by a sequential numeric column having multiple nodes to increase the DIUs and parallel copy, but it's still not utilizing the compute resource.

Comment: You can do Incremental loading using watermark column in ADF. Refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#loading-new-and-changed-files-only-by-using-lastmodifieddate).